# Chrome extension setIcon not working with dictionary

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When trying to set a new icon for my chrome extension it only lets me use the *string* option. I am trying to use the dictionary so chrome can pick up the best icon depending on the user. Here is what I have so far:

Manifest:

```
"icons": {
  "16": "images/icon.png",
  "48": "images/icon48.png",
  "128": "images/icon128.png"
},
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "images/icon.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
}...
```

content_script.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: {
  "16": "images/icon.png",
  "48": "images/icon48.png",
  "128": "images/icon128.png"
}});
```

When my code reaches the setIcon code it throws me this error:

```
Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'path': Value does not match any valid type choices.
```

I have tried a few things but the only way for this to work is to add a string instead of a dictionary. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon) are the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Chrome expects certain sizes, and if there is anything else it throws this error.

Not very informative, I agree.

Right now, the documentation says:

> If the number of image pixels that fit into one screen space unit equals `scale`, then image with size `scale * 19` will be selected. **Initially only scales 1 and 2 will be supported.**

So, it expects **only** sizes `19` and `38`. Anything else in the dictionary will result in the error above.

Note that the image does not *have* to be this exact size; it will be scaled as required.